# Do JSP/Servlet engines ignore tags in a CDATA section?

Tags: java, javascript, xhtml, jstl

I have a jspx file using XHTML (generated from Spring Roo), so to include a block of Javascript I need to wrap it in a CDATA section like this to be valid:

```
<script>
<![CDATA[
    new dijit.Tooltip(
    {
        connectId : [ "exampleId" ],
        label : "<c:out value='${exampleIdTooltip}'/>",
        position: "above"
    });
]]>
</script>
```

The trouble I'm having, I guess the CDATA is doing its job and the `<c:out`> is not being executed, it's left as literal text inside the Javascript block. If I change the file to not be XHTML then I can remove the CDATA, and then my `<c:out>` is evaluated.

What's the best way to embed JSTL tags or EL inside a block of Javascript in an XHTML file?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using CDATA, manually escape `&`, `<`, and `>` inside the script block if it's not supposed to be evaluated. Remember to escape the result of the JSTL/EL too.

Comment: The c:out needs to be evaluated though, I'm assuming if I have &lt;c:out&gt; then this won't be evaluated by the servlet engine, right?

Comment: Correct, but something like `if (numb < 10)` (javascript) should not be evaluated, so you would use `numb &lt; 10` instead of saying the whole script body is CDATA. But remember the `c:out` output needs to be escaped for javascript *and* html!  You are probably better off putting all your servlet stuff in a single json structure and referring to it in your scripts instead of using `c:out` directly.

Comment: Another alternative is simply to insert `]]><c:out>whatever</c:out><![CDATA[` wherever you need the `c:out` tag to be evaluated. This will end the previous CDATA and start a new one right afterwards.